# How to search for Possibilities to parallelize?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I have some serial code that  I have started to parallelize using Intel's TBB. My first aim was to parallelize almost all the for loops in the code (I have even parallelized for within for loop)and right now having done that I get some speedup.I am looking for more places/ideas/options to parallelize...I know this might sound a bit vague without having much reference to the problem but I am looking for generic ideas here which I can explore in my code.

Overview of algo( the following algo is run over all levels of the image starting with shortest and increasing width and height by 2 each time till you reach actual height and width).

```
For all image pairs starting with the smallest pair
    For height = 2 to image_height - 2
        Create a 5 by image_width ROI of both left and right images.
        For width = 2 to image_width - 2
            Create a 5 by 5 window of the left ROI centered around width and find best match in the right ROI using NCC
            Create a 5 by 5 window of the right ROI centered around width and find best match in the left ROI using NCC
            Disparity = current_width - best match
    The edge pixels that did not receive a disparity gets the disparity of its neighbors
    For height = 0 to image_height
        For width = 0 to image_width
            Check smoothness, uniqueness and order constraints*(parallelized separately)
    For height = 0 to image_height
        For width = 0 to image_width
            For disparity that failed constraints, use the average disparity of
            neighbors that passed the constraints
    Normalize all disparity and output to screen
```

Comment: A dataflow diagram can help find tasks that can be executed independently, in parallel.

Comment: @rwong- Added the overview.Let me know if you dont understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for some perspective, it may not always be worthwhile to parallelize something.

Just because you have a for loop where each iteration can be done independently of each other, doesn't always mean you should.

TBB has some overhead for starting those parallel_for loops, so unless you're looping a large number of times, you probably shouldn't parallelize it.

But, if each loop is extremely expensive (Like in CirrusFlyer's example) then feel free to parallelize it.

More specifically, look for times where the overhead of the parallel computation is small relative to the cost of having it parallelized.

Also, be careful about doing nested parallel_for loops, as this can get expensive. You may want to just stick with paralellizing the outer for loop.

Comment: Nested parallel_for loops are fine to have in TBB. Of course there is some overhead, but TBB's default settings (particularly, auto_partitioner) try to minimize the overhead. If the inner loop would execute faster on two cores, parallelising it may make sense, especially if the outer loop is not well balanced.

Comment: @Alexey: My point is if your loop is very cheap and there aren't many iterations, there's usually no point in making it parallel. Sure, if the execution time of the outer loop can vary it may be worthwhile to parallelize both loops, but in general you should be cautious and always measure to see if it helps.

Comment: I agree; and actually what you said is true for parallelism at any level, not only for nested stuff. I just wanted to make a point that TBB supports nested parallelism pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The silly answer is anything that is time consuming or iterative.  I use Microsoft's .NET v4.0 Task Parallel Library and one of the interesting things about their setup is its "expressed parallelism."  An interesting term to describe "attempted parallelism."  Though, your coding statements may say "use the TPL here" if the host platform doesn't have the necessary cores it will simply invoke the old fashion serial code in its place.

I have begun to use the TPL on all my projects.  Any place there are loops especially (this requires that I design my classes and methods such that there are no dependencies between the loop iterations).  But any place that might have been just good old fashion multithreaded code I look to see if it's something I can place on different cores now.

My favorite so far has been an application I have that downloads ~7,800 different URL's to analyze the contents of the pages, and if it finds information that it's looking for does some additional processing .... this used to take between 26 - 29 minutes to complete.  My Dell T7500 workstation with dual quad core Xeon 3GHz processors, with 24GB of RAM, and Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit edition now crunches the entire thing in about 5 minutes.  A huge difference for me.

I also have a publish / subscribe communication engine that I have been refactoring to take advantage of TPL (especially on "push" data from the Server to Clients ... you may have 10,000 client computers who have stated their interest in specific things, that once that event occurs, I need to push data to all of them).  I don't have this done yet but I'm REALLY LOOKING FORWARD to seeing the results on this one.

Food for thought ...